# Jenkins Extended Email - presendScript can't create file

Tags: jenkins, email-ext

I wrote the following presend script for the extended email extension to send an email only once  every 20 hours and not every build:

```
String pname = '${env.JOB_NAME}';

long minEmailGap = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 20; // 20 hours in milliseconds

File file = new File("/var/lib/jenkins/TimestampFor" + pname + ".txt");

if (file.exists() == false) {
file.createNewFile();
}
else {
long currentTime = (new Date()).getTime();

if (file.lastModified() + minEmailGap > currentTime) {
    cancel = true;
}
else {
    file.setLastModified(currentTime);
}
}
```

The following error keeps the script from completing successfully:

```
java.io.IOException: No such file or directory
    at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
    at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:1012)
    at java_io_File$createNewFile$0.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:163)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:165)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$checkedCall$3.callStatic(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallStatic(CallSiteArray.java:56)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callStatic(AbstractCallSite.java:194)
    at Script1.run(Script1.groovy:8)
    at hudson.plugins.emailext.ExtendedEmailPublisher.executeScript(ExtendedEmailPublisher.java:621)
    at hudson.plugins.emailext.ExtendedEmailPublisher.executePresendScript(ExtendedEmailPublisher.java:571)
    at hudson.plugins.emailext.ExtendedEmailPublisher.sendMail(ExtendedEmailPublisher.java:455)
    at hudson.plugins.emailext.EmailExtStep$EmailExtStepExecution.run(EmailExtStep.java:236)
    at hudson.plugins.emailext.EmailExtStep$EmailExtStepExecution.run(EmailExtStep.java:174)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution$1$1.call(AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:47)
    at hudson.security.ACL.impersonate(ACL.java:367)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution$1.run(AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:44)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Jenkins v2.235.2 has permission in /var/lib/jenkins. Everything is allowed in the script security settings. The file is not being created and in turn not evaluated. What is going wrong here?

Comment: Can you please share the job name it fails on? Is possible that it has "/" in the name?

Comment: I'm using a multibranch pipeline, the branch name is "development" and the pipeline's name is wvgfrontend.

Comment: And is it reside in a folder?

Answer (score 0):

`JOB_NAME` may contain forward slashes (`/`) if the job is located inside a directory, and then your script will try to create a file in a directory that does not exist.

You can replace every `/` in your `JOB_NAME` with an underscore (`_`):

```
String pname = '${env.JOB_NAME}.replace('/', '_')';
```

Comment: After doing this I still get the same error. I also tried to drop the /var/lib/jenkins and use just /. Then I got a permission denied. Sorry for the long response time, the build takes pretty long to run.

Comment: Is the job running on the master node of Jenkins? Or on an agent?

Comment: It is running on the master node, I have no agents.

Comment: OK. Can you please print the string after assigning it using:  `println "${pname}` and then share it?